# How to run ruby as nobody

Tags: ruby, unix, settings

I am trying to build a service that will only run my ruby app without having a shell and only have a directory that contains the app. I have created a user using the `adduser --system --disabled-login --disabled-password --home /usr/local/appname appname` When using the command `sudo -u appname ruby app.rb` The command fails saying `ruby command not found`

Comment: Are you using `rbenv` or `rvm`? Try using the full path to your `ruby` binary.

Comment: I am using rbenv

Comment: "Try using the full path to your `ruby` binary."